# How do I pass a char and a char* from C# to C++/CLI?

Tags: c#, c++-cli, char

The title contains all. How do I pass a char and char* from C# to C++/CLI.
Here is my cpp function declaration:

```
int ForexCpp::FXCrossDate(
             char usdTypeOfPeriods,
             char *holidayFile,
             TDate%         result);  /* (O) Resulting FX cross date */
```

In C#, char and char * are exposed as sByte and sByte*...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have chosen to use C++/CLI rather than P/invoke the natural way to handle this is to pass a .net string rather than a `char*`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you done any research on this yet? The internet is full of this type of stuff. 
Anyways, this page on MSDN lists various ways to convert between string types:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235631.aspx

The one you want is at the bottom of the page.